# How to show that $l^{\infty}(T)$ with sup norm is complete?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a set, and let $l^{\infty}(T)$ denote the set of all bounded functions $T \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
I want to show that $l^{\infty}(T)$ together with the norm $ ||.||_{\infty}:=sup_{t \in T}|x(t)|$ is Banach.

I showed that  $l^{\infty}(T)$ is a vector space and that $||.||_{\infty}$ is a norm.
Now I am struggling to show completeness.

I will outline what I have so far:
I need to show that there exists some element $x \in l^{\infty}(T)$ such that $||x_n-x|| \rightarrow 0$.

My attempt this far was:
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a cauchy sequence.Now take some element $t_0 \in l^{\infty}(T)$ and consider the sequence $(x_1(t_0),x_2(t_0),...,x_n(t_0))$ which is in $\mathbb{R}$. I will denote this sequence as $(x_n(t_0))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Next I need to show that this sequence is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$. It is obvious that $|x_n(t)|\leq ||x||_{\infty}$. Thus for every $t \in T$ that I choose I know that $(x_n(t_0))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has to have a convergent subsequence. And here is the problem, I don't know how to continue from here on.

Comment: $(x_n(t))$ is Cauchy, hence convergent, for each $t$. Define $x(t)=\lim x_n(t)$.

Comment: I don't really understand why one can argue that if $x_n$ is cauchy then $x_n(t)$ is also cauchy (in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: $|x_n(t)-x_m(t)| \leq \|x_n-x\|$. BTW, you should first write down the definition of a Cauchy sequence in your space.

Comment: Thank you very much.